# Unable to change source image on button click event?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
 var a;
 var b:Sprite;
 function Start () {
     a=GetComponent.<UI.Image>();   
 }

 function Clicked(){
     a.SourceImage=b;
 }
```

The function clicked is called on a OnClick event.
The error I get is: *MissingFieldException: UnityEngine.UI.Image.SourceImage*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is quite self-explanatory...

Simply change `a.SourceImage=b;` to `a.sprite=b;`.

Look for [**Image** component manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) next time: can be useful ;)

*Hope this helps,*